# Using Vim warning style in gVim

Tags: vim, gtk

When for example an edited file is changed outside of Vim, Vim issues a warning and offers to reload the file.  In command line Vim a green text on the bottom appears, but in gVim there is a GTK+ popup window instead.  I like Vim behaviour more, and I'd like to have it in gVim as well, how can I change that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an option to enable that behavior in the GUI version of Vim.  If `c`
is set in `guioptions`, console-like dialogs are used instead of graphical
popup ones.

```
:set guioptions+=c
```

Comment: +1. To clarify ib's answer, add the line `set guioptions+=c` to your ~/.vimrc file.